# How to differentiate between two files in shell script

Tags: bash

I have a file `a.txt` which has

```
a,20
b,30
c,40
```

Another `b.txt` has

```
a,40
b,60
d,3
```

I need to iterate the first column and check if a variable is not present in the second file (here `c` is not present) and send out a mail with that variable name.

Answer (score 0):

To extract just the first column, you can use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f1 file.txt
```

- `-d` specifies the delimiter
- `-f` specifies columns to extract

To check for lines common to a pair of files, use `comm`:

```
comm file1 file2
```

`comm` outputs three columns: the 1st one lists things unique to file1, the 2nd one things unique to file2, the 3rd things common to both. You can tell `comm` to omit a column by specifying its number as an argument. `comm` needs the input files to be sorted, though. I usually set `$LC_ALL` to `C` when sorting to avoid any influence of the locale.

So, the answer to your question is

```
comm -23 <(cut -f1 -d, a.txt | LC_ALL=C sort) <(cut -f1 -d, b.txt | LC_ALL=C sort)
```

Comment: Thank u choroba it's working as a command but when I use this in the script I am getting all the values present in a.txt.any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me with the files you provided. Please show files for which the command doesn't work.

Comment: I am not directly referring to the file name instead I used config file and took the file name from there.my command is like this comm -23 <(cut -f1 -d, $Current | LC_ALL=C sort) <(cut -f1 -d, $Curren1 | LC_ALL=C sort).Here Current and Current1 are referring to a.txt and b.txt which are defined in a config file.

Comment: Note that `$Curren1` and `$Current1` are two different variables. Also, you should double quote them in case the filename contained whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Possible `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}' b.txt a.txt
```